# Undefined function: 'FORMAT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using databricks and using Spark SQL and in the query `FORMAT(Date,'ddMMyyyy'))` where Date is a column in the table. And here's the error I'm getting:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'FORMAT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database

Is there any alternative to FORMAT? Or can I make the FORMAT function work somehow? The query is kinda huge with a lot of joins and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FORMAT` is an SQL Server function, the equivalent of which in Spark SQL should be [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#date_format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, 'ddMMyyyy') FROM mytable
```